# Game scoreboard on Azure

Tags: database, azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

could you please recommend me an alternative solution for storing game scores on Azure cloud? I am looking for a **managed**, **cheap to run** and **easily scalable up and down** storage option.

Input data: `{ "player": 1, "score": 10 }` (the score may be already calculated, no need to sum up.)

There should be an option to make 2 types of queries:
1. Get player's position in the scoreboard.
2. Get positions (player and score) between position X and Y.

The application can not tell the position of player in the scoreboard during the write time - the back-end database solution should provide that information, or the data layout should allow fast computation of position between all players.
Non real-time accuracy is acceptable.

Current back-end technology choice: Azure Web App (.NET Core), Storage (Table, Blob, Queues).
With SQL server it obvious how to do that, but **I would like to avoid** bringing the SQL server to the technology stack. Keeping in memory is also not an option because of multiple web servers.

Do you have any idea how such data may be stored and retrieved using any other Azure service? DocumentDB, Data Lake, any other?

Comment: Azure Table Storage seems appropriate for you

Comment: Using a single partition key?

Comment: (1) how many players do you foresee? hundreds? thousands? millions? (2) you want to track positions of all the players or just the top 10? (3) the `X` and `Y` are fixed segments (like 1-10, 11-20,..) or are they start/range? like (1-next10, next10, ...). Note that with fixed segmentation, some segments may turn up empty.

Comment: Realistically tens of thousands, but let's pretend millions, because I would like to learn how different the solution would be in such case. There is a need to 1. Track top100 players 2. Provide a player (player1) his position with his immediate competitors: #3010 player5 score; #3009 player1 score; #3008 player7 score. To make things simplier, we can ignore everything below #10000 and show "Your position is #10000+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with calculating *position in a list* is that ranking (and window operations in general) is difficult to do when your data can be distributed across multiple servers. It becomes an expensive operation as your data grows, and doesn't scale well.

Data Lake does support window functions, including [RANK() and DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-use-window-functions#ranking-functions). You'll want to give this a good test with some representative data to see what performance is like.

---

The other option is to pre-calculate the rankings at certain intervals and "cache" the full scoreboard into Table Storage; if it's acceptable for there to be a delay to users (e.g. you could say the rankings refresh every hour)

Then you could have a scheduled WebJob that:

1. Reads all the score records where score is higher than a threshold, ordered on score
2. Creates a new table for player rank e.g. `player-scores-170401-124200`
3. Creates a new table for overall ranking e.g. `scoreboard-170401-124200`
4. Writes the ranked scoreboard into the new tables in batches

In this way, you can query `player-scores` on `PartitionKey=player` to get an individual ranking, and query `scoreboard` with an inequality filter to get a window of positions.

Querying (which is the operation you probably should optimise for) becomes very cheap and easy, as it's a single transaction for each piece of info.

Running the calculation also isn't too expensive, and transaction costs are the thing you'll want to keep an eye on. Assuming *n* score records:

- You can read in batches of 100. Transactions ~= n / 100
- You can write to the same partition in batches of 100. Transactions ~= 2n / 100
- You can choose to keep historic rankings, or drop the entire table in a single transaction

So your total transactions for 1M records is:

`1000000*3/100 = 30,000 per run`

Do that every hour for a day (720k transactions), and it'll cost you roughly 2-3 cents a day (not including storage costs, of course). That counts as cheap to run in my book :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use tables then your 1st query is easy, you could use player id (unique identifier for a player whatever you choose that to be) as your partition key and score can be a property of the same entity. When you want to read that back (your query 1) you simply make a point query with the unique player id and get the score.

Your 2nd query is a bit more tricky. You would want to avoid downloading the entire table and do an in memory sorting on the client side that is worst of both client and table service worlds combined.

So a  different partition key needs to be picked here to optimize for the 2nd query. One thing you could do is to create a bucket of ranges and get a unique hash for that range. Ie. if you are writing a player with a position 19 and you pick your bucket size as 50, that goes to your first bucket of players with positions between 1 - 50. Before writing the player with position 19 to table, your facade (or adapter whatever you call it) layer of code in client will detect that this goes to the 1st bucket, generate a hash for that bucket and write the player to the table with the generated hash for bucket 1- 50 as partition key and the actual player unique id as its row key and the rest of the properties.

the hash you generate for the bucket could simply be  hash of lower and upper limits of the bucket etc. make sure to use a cryptographic hash though not Object.GethashCode because that could return different hash values for the exact same object and should not be used for his purpose.

When you want to get all players between range X and Y you would need to query those partitions that you know which covers that range and not the whole table. And you ware going to query the partitions with the exact partition key (hash value representing the bucket) so it would be efficient.

When you are inserting a player you would need to create 2 entities 1 for your first query and second for your second query and insert both. This process is also called denormalizing the data to optimize for different query needs. Hope this helps understand a bit how to optimize this using Azure tables.

Comment: For both queries I don't know the position.

Comment: You do not need to know the position of the player for your queries you only need to know the position when you are actually writing the player to table storage. For your first query you query the table wit the partition key that is the unique id of the player. For your 2nd query you query the table with the hash value that corresponds to that range X-Y as the partition key. You may need to do a few of these queries if your range spans across multiple buckets but you still donot need the position for your queries

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for not being clear. I don't know the position during thee write time. The application can provide only the player id and his score. I am looking for a technology/data layout, which can tell me the position.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Table Storage is benefit for storing pure data and it is inexpensive and easy to scale. But it is not benefit for complex query. You can save some money by choosing Table Storage if it meets your needs.  prices range from 4.5 to 12 cents per gigabyte/month.

Azure DocumentDB is a distributed document database. It is more capable than Azure Table Storage, but is also more expensive. Price: at 25 cents per gigabyte/month.

Azure Data Lake Store is an optimized storage for big data analytics workloads, we often use it to batch, interactive, streaming analytics and machine learning data such as log files, IoT data, click streams, large datasets

It is better to choose Azure Table Storage if it could meet your needs. Based on your description, I suggest you use Azure Table Storage and optimize the query by using different partition keys.  For how to design a scalable and performant tables, link below is for your reference.

[Azure Storage Table Design Guide: Designing Scalable and Performant Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide)

> Get player's position in the scoreboard.

If we want to get the position(ranking), the best way for storing the data is using score as partition key. If we only know the id of  current player, we need to get the score of current player before querying the position. To query a player based on player id, it is better to store another copy of game data in Azure Table Storage by setting  player id as partition key.

> Get positions (player and score) between position X and Y.

Use score as partition key is suitable for this scenario.

In summary, I suggest you store two different copies of game data. One is use score as partition key and another is use player id as partition key.

> For both queries I don't know the position

The result data of your query is order by partition key. So the result count is the position(ranking) for your player.

For example, after setting score as partition key, you could use partition key less than a score(ex. 10) to query a range of entities and the entities count is the position of the player whose score is 10.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am missing the most important part - how the position is calculated? The application knows only the fact - the score of specific player.

Comment: Regarding Data Lake, is it a good technology to accept events from the application and regularly calculate positions of all players and persist the results in a Azure Storage blob/table?

Comment: If you store positions in azure storage, every change to score will need to re-calculate positions and update all the data. If the score will change frequently, it will spend lots of time on the score changes.

Comment: Regarding your answer, it does not sound it will work - if I use score as a partition key, to get the position of player, I will have to read all rows which has a higher score as partition key. If you suggested to have additional table with PlayerID as a partition key and a position as a field - the position is not known, until all rows are scanned as mentioned before.

Comment: What about adding a additional table which log the score and how many numbers of players reach this score? We can set the score as partition key. When we modify the score of a player, for example changing score from 10 to 30 for player1, we need to decrease a count for score 10 and increase a count for score 30. We could easily get the position by count all the numbers of players whose score is max than the player's score.

Comment: Very interesting approach. If I understood that correctly, the first part should work well, but for getting the position we should scan almost the whole table. And if the difference between the low and the high score is big, there may be a lot of rows to read. Additional index tables may help, where the score is split into chunks, like this: 1_100 count1, 101_200 count2, etc.

Comment: Yes, add additional table will increase the query speed.